# Show data in input

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm new with this all, i hope u can help me!

I have a name pickers in a 'var data', like this:

```
var data = [{"name":"firstname lastname", "username":"admin",}]
```

I would like to show the picked name as text, there i have the next line:

```
d3.select("#name h1")
 .text(data[picked].name);

<div id="name"><h1></h1></div>
```

**[this works!]**

I would like to get the username in an input. I have this:

```
d3.select("#username")
 .text(data[picked].username);
<input id="username">
```

But this doesn't work for me.

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

```
d3.select("#username").val(data[picked].username);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('#username').value = data[picked].username;
```

Try this

Comment: Please provide some meaningful explanation along with your code to explain the OP how this will solve his problem.